# Why is $(a,+\infty)$ part of the topology generated by the base $\mathfrak{B}=\{B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\ | B=[a, +\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}\}$?

Tags: general-topology

If we consider

$\mathfrak{B}=\{B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\ | B=[a, +\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the base of a topology over $\mathbb{R}$, whose open sets are the positive half-lines with closed or open endpoint, plus $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$. ...(1)

In fact, if we considered a family $ \mathfrak{A} =\{A_i=[a_i,+\infty) | a_i \in \mathbb{R} , i \in I\} \subseteq \mathfrak{B}$, where I is a subset of indices and let $\alpha=inf a_i$(eventualy $\alpha = -\infty)$. ...(2)

Now $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=(\alpha, + \infty)$ if $\alpha \neq  a_i $ $  \forall i$, otherwise it coincides with $[\alpha, +\infty)$ ...(3)

**My questions**

(1)Why are half-lines with open endpoints ($(a,+\infty$) part of the topology? It looks like intersecting and unifying all I can get are half-lines with closed endpoind

(2)I guess there is a typo here, the inf of a number makes no sense, it should be $\alpha=inf A_i$ instead of $\alpha=inf a_i$

(3) Why is $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i=(\alpha, + \infty)$ if $\alpha \neq  a_i $ ? It looks like any union, even an infinite one would always yield a set of the form $[a,+\infty)$

Comment: Quick remark: note that $$(a, \infty) = \bigcup_{b > a}[b, \infty).$$

Comment: That is actually what I don't get

Comment: A concrete example is that $(0, \infty) = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} [1/n, \infty)$, for example. Do you see how you would prove that, and how that relates to your question?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: To show that two sets are equal, the usual approach is to show that one is a subset of the other. Did you try doing that? Do you find showing both the inclusions tough?

Comment: @ Izaak van Dongen I know intuitively it is true , but I don't know who to formally prove it. I guess the approach is the one  Aryaman Maithani is suggesting

Comment: As Aryaman says, can you show that each set is a subset of the other? This amounts to the following: $0 < x$, if and only if there is some $n$ such that $x > 1 / n$. This is basically the Archimedean property of the reals. By the way, the notation with the infimum should be read as $\alpha = \inf \{a_i : i \in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen wouldn't $\alpha=inf A_i$ be the same?

Comment: No, $\inf A_i = a_i$. We want $\alpha$ to be the least upper bound of the union of all the intervals.

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen  Sorry, I meant $\alpha=inf \mathfrak{A} $

Comment: But $\inf{\mathfrak U}$ doesn't really make any sense. $\mathfrak U$ is a set of sets, not a set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n >1$ be an integer, and define $A_n = [a+\frac1n,+\infty)$. For all $n$, $A_n \in \mathcal{T}$, the topology generated by $\mathfrak{B}$. So $A = \cup_{n>1} A_n \in \mathcal{T}$ by the definition of the topology $\mathcal{T}$. Notice that $A = (a,+\infty)$.

Comment: When n goes to infinity, shouldn't a be part of the union?

Comment: For a number $x$, being in the union says that there exists some $n > 1$ such that $x\in A_n$. So there exists $n$ such that $x \geqslant a+ \frac1n >a$. Thus, $a$ can not be in the union

Comment: For $\mathfrak{B}=\{B \subseteq \mathbb{R}\ | B=[a, +\infty), a \in \mathbb{R}\}$  to be a base of the topology, I need $\bigcup_{a \in  \mathbb{R}} [a, +\infty) = \mathbb{R}$, why is that true?, doesn't the right side implies we should always have a number as left endpoint?